# Remove a sentence starting with a word in R?

Tags: r, string, twitter, text-mining

I have a tweet text like this in R.

```
"RT @SportClipsUT125: #SavingLivesLooksGood with #RedCross. Donate this month &amp; Get free haircut cpn. https://somewebsite https://somewebsite…"
```

How can I remove all the links (to remove duplicate tweets) so that the following tweet actually returns the string below?

```
"RT @SportClipsUT125: #SavingLivesLooksGood with #RedCross. Donate this month &amp; Get free haircut"
```

I have tried this:

```
gsub('https*','',test_str)
```

but it returns

```
"RT @SportClipsUT125: #SavingLivesLooksGood with #RedCross. Donate this           
month &amp; Get free haircut cpn. ://somewebsite ://somewebsite…"
```

Comment: You need to put the quantifier on the character you want to repeat. `\\S` is anything but a space character: `gsub('http\\S*', '', "RT @SportClipsUT125: #SavingLivesLooksGood with #RedCross. Donate this month & Get free haircut cpn. https://somewebsite https://somewebsite…")`

Comment: maybe you can send the same query to twitter again, with -RT appended (case sensitive). This will remove retweets.

Comment: Thanks @alistaire this actually works! So what your code is doing is actually removing everything after https and a space?

Comment: It looks for a pattern that of "http" followed by any character except a space, repeated 0 or more times, and replaces it with nothing. It will actually leave trailing spaces, but you could add on to address that, if it matters.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to change your gsub command:

<strike>`gsub("http[s]*://[[:alnum:]]*", "", test_str)` This will correctly remove URL's, both http and https versions</strike>

@alistaire's suggestion in the comments actually works in more cases is more understandable `gsub('http\\S*', "", test_str)` will remove anything starting with http. It will stop when it finds a space (which URL's do not have)

`gsub("(RT|via)((?:\\b\\W*@\\w+)+)", "", test_str)` to remove retweets

`gsub("@\\w+", "", test_str)` remove Atpeople

I would highly recommend putting your data in a corpus (a special data format), it makes things like removing often repeated words and URL's very easy.
If you have a corpus of data you could do this:

```
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(my_data))
corpus = tm_map(corpus,content_transformer(function(x) iconv(x, to='UTF8', sub='byte')))
removeURL <- function(x) {gsub('http\\S*', "", x)}
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(removeURL))
```

Awesome link for examples on how to do all this: 
[Text Mining Guide on Rpubs](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/31867_8236987cf0a8444e962ccd2aec46d9c3.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I tried gsub("http[[:alnum:]]*", "", test_str) but it only got rid of "http" and leaving the rest of the short link there?

Comment: Oops, fixed it (in the strikethrough code), but @alistaire's suggestion is better for that specific problem.